# Execute dynamically generated Postgres 13 SQL (that returns a resultset) in a plain SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm doing a programming challenge. I mention this *not* because I require help with the challenge itself - I've already devised a solution, but I can't find a way to make the solution work with the technical constraints Postgres imposes

I believe the challenge will require a dynamic query to solve, because a single SQL query must produce an output where the number and name of columns output varies each time it is run. The challenge has 3 scenarios, and the same query must solve each, but the columns expected as output are driven by the rows in the input data, which varies per scenario - I can't see how that is solved without building a dynamic string and executing it.

In essence if the input data is:

```
  CountOfSales, ProductName
  1,            Chocolate
  2,            Cola
```

Then the output needs to be

```
  Chocolate, Cola, Total
  1,         2,    3
```

If the input is

```
  CountOfSales, ProductName
  100,          Burgers
  200,          Fries
  300,          Shakes
```

Then the output needs to be

```
  Burgers, Fries, Shakes, Total
  100,     200,   300,    600
```

The real challenge is more complex than this, as is the query I've written that builds the dynamic SQL but this should suffice to explain my problem.

Suppose I've created a single query that writes an SQL that generates these results; essentially like:

```
  SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CountOfSales, ' AS ', ProductName), ','), ', ', SUM(CountOfSales), ' as Total FROM Input') FROM Input
```

The output of running this would be:

```
  --when executed against test 1
  'SELECT 1 as Chocolate, 2 as Cola, 3 as Total'

  --executed against test 2
  'SELECT 100 as Burgers, 200 as Fries, 300 as Shakes, 600 as Total'
```

That is to say when the challenge SQL i've written is run it generates a complete, valid SQL string that can be run to solve the challenge for that scenario

When I copy and paste these generated queries into the run box and run them, these solve their individual scenarios (the first one passes test 1 but not test 2, the second passes test 2 but not test 1..)

But I can't find a way to use the original statement such that:

1. it runs to generate a string containing the SQL needed to solve the challenge
2. it then executes the generated SQL to a resultset
3. returns the resultset to pass the test

I've read a lot of SO questions about running PG dynamic SQL, with advice like "use a do block" but putting a code like:

```
DO $$
DECLARE q TEXT;
BEGIN
  q:= (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount), ' as Total') FROM Sales);

  EXECUTE q INTO x;
  
  SELECT * FROM x;
END $$;
```

I get

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near
> "$$ DECLARE q TEXT;

I read that online fiddle type sites might not like $$ strings, so I swapped it to `'` string with doubled up `''` everywhere inside; the error just complains of unterminated `'` string

I try without the block:

```
EXECUTE (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount), ' as Total') FROM Sales) INTO x;
```

> Syntax error near (

I try to assign the result of `(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount)` into a variable and execute the variable; no joy there yet either

I've found advice to create a function that executes SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.exec(
text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE $1 ; 
END 
$BODY$;


SELECT * FROM exec(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount), ' as Total') FROM Sales)
```

Or trying to get the generated SQL into a variable and `exec()` that.. None of them have worked out, always some syntax error

All these advices feel like something that should be carried out in a PLPGSQL block, and I get the feeling I don't have that; I think I have a plain SQL statement.. I can run a query like:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

SELECT ... FROM crosstab...
```

But maybe that's just a plain statement as well, despite the presence of a non-SELECT operation

I haven't tried query-to-xml or similar, because I think this is still no good because you can't extract the XML back to a tabular resultset with varying column nmaes without some element of dynamism to the query you execute to do the extracting

To be clear, I'm not asking for help with the challenge itself; I've already written a complex query that is capable of forming a dynamic SQL that can pass the tests of the challenge. What I'm struggling with is executing that query string immediately after I've built it

How do I run an SQL contained in a string emitted by an SQL, without access to a PGPLSQL context?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to craft a real world (and correct) solution to something a testing tool accepts.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run an SQL contained in a string emitted by an SQL, without access to a PGPLSQL context?

We can use a `DO` block to create a PGPLSQL context within a statement

This was in error:

```
DO $$
DECLARE q TEXT;
BEGIN
  q:= (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount), ' as Total') FROM Sales);

  EXECUTE q INTO x;
  
  SELECT * FROM x;
END $$;
```

This would have worked out:

```
DO $$
DECLARE q TEXT;
BEGIN
  q:= (SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Amount, ' AS ', product_id), ','), ', ', SUM(amount), ' as Total') FROM Sales);

  EXECUTE q;
  
END $$;

SELECT * FROM temp;
```